# Registering to push notifications results in an "Invalid Action" error on Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm trying to use PhoneGap's push notification plugin, but receive and error when trying to register for push notifications on Android (haven't tested on other platforms). For testing purposes I created a minimal sample app that reproduces this problem.

[Install sample app](https://build.phonegap.com/apps/482578/share)

[View sample app source code](https://github.com/rotev/phonegap-build-push-notifications-test)

Your help is greatly appriciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I wasn't using the plugin as I should have; instead of writing this:

```
pushNotification.register(pg_success_handler, pg_error_handler, {
  "senderID": "<sender id>",
  "ecb": on_pg_gcm_notification
});
```

I should have written this:

```
pushNotification.register(pg_success_handler, pg_error_handler, {
  "senderID": "<sender id>",
  "ecb": "on_pg_gcm_notification"
});
```

The registration works now :)